# Why grounding a battery to car chassis?

Tags: batteries, ground, automotive

I'm about to install a voltage sensitive relay which will be in between my car battery and my auxiliary battery in my van. When doing research for this, I find diagrams like this:

[image: VSR Diagram]

What confuses me here, is ground, and if I should be grounding my aux battery to the chassis, and what would be the purpose of this?

In this schema, does ground just mean that the negative poles should be connected? I understood it like just a shortcut, instead of having to close the circuit in the schema, you can just use the ground symbol, which means the negative poles should be connected to each other. Or does it actually mean grounding to the chassis?

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I've done research for this but I haven't been able to grasp it yet...

Thank you.

Comment: The chassis of a car or van is typically used as the return path for most circuits.

Comment: Have a look in your van and you should see that the existing battery negative strap is bolted to chassis which acts ac a return conductor for almost everything else including starter, lights, fans, etc.

Comment: One should not be building a custom vehicle electrical system until there is a much better understanding of things like this, and far more important issues *not* being sufficiently considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chassis, metal body on a monocoque car is used as the negative wire, or ground.

This saves on needing two cables (supply and return) to each device or light etc. The accountants save on the cost by reducing the number of cables and often by minimizing the cable size used to each device.

So each battery negative is connected to the chassis, you could control the negative instead of the positive but it does depend on the total of what you want to achieve and not with that particular relay which has an override function.

Just remember to ground or provide a return for devices or lights on cars that have fibreglass panels :)

Also take care as many cars before about 1965 were positive earth...

Comment: Hmm, so the whole chassi becomes the negative pole? Isn't this dangerous? Or are all the appliances also grounded within the car then?

Comment: So this is only done to save on cables, not on stabilising voltages and for security purposes?

Comment: @mtnptrsn more danger from poor or drunk drivers than connecting the chassis / body to the negative pole...

Comment: @mtnptrsn the voltage goes form about 12v to 15.3V so any device that needs a stable supply tends to be connected via a voltage stabiliser, which when they failed allowed the revving of the engine to give you more fuel as the gauge would move as the engine revs increased.,

Comment:  Okay, thank you. So I don't need to ground my aux battery to the chassi then? There is no need to do that in order to prevent voltage instability?

Comment: Just realised we're working with 12 volts as well so no need to think too much about safety..

Comment: @mtnptrsn you should be concerned with safety, you can set a car on fire if you get things wrong and you can solder and even weld using the power from a 12 volt battery, given it can delivery 1000A or more depending on conditions.

Comment: "*So I don't need to ground my aux battery to the chassi then?*" Nobody said that and if you don't do that how will current return to the battery? You really do need to think about safety. The word is **chassis**, not chassi. (**chassis** (US: /ˈtʃæsi/, UK: /ˈʃæsi/; plural **chassis** /-iz/))

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I am aware of that. What I meant was that you shouldn't be concerned to get a dangerous electrical shock. But of course, I am aware of the other risks :) Thank you!!

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the correction. Yes, sorry, I meant specifically that you don't need to be concerned with getting an electrical shock. Of course, there are other things you need to keep in mind.

Instead of grounding it to the chassis I can just use a cable back to the negative pole. I prefer doing this instead of using the chassis.

Answer (score 3):

The earthing symbol, in an automotive electrical system schematic, does signify actual connection to chassis.

The path from the power source to the loads, in an automobile, is through copper cables whereas the return path is through the low resistance steel chassis.

The advantages of such a system are:

1. Cost savings in copper cables to the extent of 50%.
2. Reduction in vehicle weight to the extent of 50% of the total weight of copper that would be otherwise required.
3. Space savings to the extent of 50% of the total volume of copper cables that would otherwise be required.

Towards this end the negative terminals (generally) of all electrical sources and loads in a vehicle are connected to the chassis.

Likewise, this concept is equally valid for the electrical system in a caravan.